# Laravel Cron Job scheduled task not working

Tags: laravel, cron

I am trying to update a status automatically with a scheduled task. I am not sure how to debug the issue as I am new to cron jobs. I have created the cronjob and added it the kernel. However, it doesn't execute.

**cronOffer.php**

```php
protected $signature = 'update:offer';
protected $description = 'update expired offers status ';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    $RSS = Rss::where('RSS_Status', '!=', 6)->first();
    $Projects = Project::where('RSS_ID', $RSS->RSS_ID)->get();

    foreach ($Projects as $Project) {

        $applications = Application::where(['A_ID' => $Project->A_ID, 'Status_ID' => 2])->get();
        foreach ($applications as $application) {
            $current_time = Carbon::now();
            $OfferDeadline = $Project->updated_at; //->addDays(2)

            if ($current_time >= $OfferDeadline) {
                $application->Status_ID = 6;
                $application->save();
            }
            $next = $application->S_Rank + 1;

            if ($application->Status_ID === 6) {
                $waiting = Application::where(['A_ID' => $Project->A_ID, 'Status_ID' => 3, 'S_Rank' => $next])->first();
                $waiting->Status_ID = 2;
                $waiting->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```php
protected $commands = [
    // Register corn commands (scheduled)
    Commands\cronOffer::class
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    //->dailyAt('09:30');
    $schedule->command('update:offer')
        ->everyMinute();
}

protected function commands()
{
    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

Comment: you also need to add the following Cron entry to your server: `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. you did it?

Comment: how I do it ? I am using xampp(apache) for development and going to use iis for production

Comment: I have found out that I need to add it in windows Task Scheduler

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to do it on windows. What I was saying is for linux based systems, where you can do it with `crontab -e` and adding that line, which will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute.